# acceder propiedades de descendiente de mySQLi en php

Tags: php, poo

Estimados 
  he extendido la clase mysqli en php pero al hacer `print_r` no se muestran las propiedades publicas que he agregado a la clase:

acá un ejemplo:

```
<?php
  // define una nueva clase 
class miClase extends mysqli{

public $miPropiedad;
public $miOtraPropiedad;

public function __construct ( $host='localhost',$username='user',$passwd='1234',$dbname='base' ){
    $this->miPropiedad = 'Hola';
    parent::__construct ( $host,$username,$passwd,$dbname );
    $this->miOtraPropiedad = 'Chao';
}
}// class

$miObjeto = new miClase();
echo $miObjeto->miPropiedad ,"\n";     // las nuevas propiedades son accesible
echo $miObjeto->miOtraPropiedad ,"\n";

print_r( $miObjeto );  // no muestra las nuevas propiedades
```

La salida de esto es:

```
Hola
Chao
miClase Object
(
    [affected_rows] =>
    [client_info] =>
    [client_version] => 50011
    [connect_errno] => 1045
    [connect_error] => Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    [errno] =>
    [error] =>
    [error_list] =>
    [field_count] =>
    [host_info] =>
    [info] =>
    [insert_id] =>
    [server_info] =>
    [server_version] =>
    [stat] =>
    [sqlstate] =>
    [protocol_version] =>
    [thread_id] =>
    [warning_count] =>
)
```

he probado con reescribir `__debugInfo()` pero no es llamado nunca :(

¿Alguna idea de como hacer visibles las propiedades agregadas?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando "**Reflection**"

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('miClase');
$props = $class->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
var_dump($props);
```

Mas info aqui:
http://php.net/manual/es/book.reflection.php